# Downloading Photos from a .txt file

Tags: r

I have a .txt file that contains photos in the following format

https://link.com/images/ff500111-23f5-4bba-afbf-.jpg

https://link.com/images/ff272ccd-caae-4c17-b9e6-561b04e77472.jpg

https://link.com/images/ff1f42fb-69f9-433b-b2ff.jpg

https://link.com/images/feee6fc3-ce18-8fae224214b5.jpg

https://link.com/images/febb3dd5-2c01-46ad8ffc4618.jpg

I want to write an R function that will loop over the link and download the photos in a folder. How do I go about that?

Comment: Do you only photo links in the text file? Can you share sample of the text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following :

If the text file is called `'temp.txt'`, use `readLines` to read it and use `Map` to download every photo.

```
photo_links <- readLines('temp.txt')
Map(download.file, photo_links, basename(photo_links))
```

This should download the phots in your working directory with names `ff500111-23f5-4bba-afbf-.jpg`, `ff272ccd-caae-4c17-b9e6-561b04e77472.jpg` etc.